# Changing elements position at breakpoint in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Footer Image]
I am making the footer in bootstrap which have links like Features, About, FQS, Contact us and logo-image(Hide for copyrights).

For large screens, the position of elements like links and logo-image are fine.
But for medium screens "links" started to display vertically, rather than displaying horizontally and logo-image moves downwards the link, as you can observe in picture provided.
Here i want 2 changes.

1)The links must display horizontally even at medium or small screen.

2) As soon as it reaches to the break-point, the elements should swap the position.(The logo-image should display at link's location and vice versa).

Code:

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h5 align="center" class="copyRightFooterH">BF2F</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h3 id="FH"><a class="Features">Features</a></h3>
                                    </br>
                                    <a href="About.php" class="about">About</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h3 id="FH"><a class="FQS">FQS</a></h3>
                                    </br>
                                    <a href="#" class="contactus">Contact us</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8" align="right">
                                <img src="images/Logo Name2.png" class="" width="350" height="125" alt=""/>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h5 align="center" class="copyRightFooterH">Copy-Right &copy; 2015-2017;</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div><!--End Row-->
            </div><!--End container-->
        </div><!--End container-fluid-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the css outside of bootstrap by giving the logo a specific class.  Bootstrap is great framework, adding the custom CSS will let you leverage that framework and still add the manipulations you need.  Hope that this helps.

Here is the working codepen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxJzQd?editors=1100

HTML Changes

```
  <div class="col-md-8 logo">
       <img src="images/Logo Name2.png" class="" width="350" height="125" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.logo { 
  text-align:center; 
}

 /*optional stuffs */ 
.logo img{ width:100%; height:auto;}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .logo { text-align:right;}
   /*optional stuffs */ 
  .logo img {width:initial; height:initial;}
}
```

Comment: Thnks !
But it's the solution of my 2nd problem. It doesn't solve my first problem

Comment: If you show an example of what your looking for on that I can help out, but I'm a little confused by the question of the first problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are saying at MEDIUM screen size have this column layout:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h3 id="FH"><a class="Features">Features</a></h3>
                                    </br>
                                    <a href="About.php" class="about">About</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h3 id="FH"><a class="FQS">FQS</a></h3>
                                    </br>
                                    <a href="#" class="contactus">Contact us</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8" align="right">
                                <img src="images/Logo Name2.png" class="" width="350" height="125" alt=""/>
                            </div>

                    </div>
```

## col-md-*

Only effect medium screen sizes and above. If you want to target every device you would use col-xs-*

Like so...

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <h3 id="FH"><a class="Features">Features</a></h3>
                                    </br>
                                    <a href="About.php" class="about">About</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <h3 id="FH"><a class="FQS">FQS</a></h3>
                                    </br>
                                    <a href="#" class="contactus">Contact us</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8" align="right">
                                <img src="images/Logo Name2.png" class="" width="350" height="125" alt=""/>
                            </div>

                    </div>
```

I believe this is the issue you are talking about. But it does not help since you provide no JSFiddle link for people to help you easily. I would recommend you attach JSFiddle link in future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove div with form-group class as you have your col stacked.

Try this:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h5 align="center" class="copyRightFooterH">BF2F</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <h3 id="FH"><a class="Features">Features</a></h3>
            <br/>
            <a href="About.php" class="about">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <h3 id="FH"><a class="FQS">FQS</a></h3>
            <br/>
            <a href="#" class="contactus">Contact us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <img src="images/Logo Name2.png" class="" width="350" height="125" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h5 align="center" class="copyRightFooterH">Copy-Right &copy; 2015-2017;</h5>
    </div>
</div><!--End container-fluid-->
```

Regards.

Comment: I edit my post and add example, if you need to stack for small screen use col-sm-xx instead col-xs-xx.

Comment: Where is your example?

Comment: Yeah it work, I do this in brackets... I can post entire file, maybe you have trouble with imports, css rules ?